# Is it possible to mock "require" or "require_once" statement with Kahlan?

Tags: php, unit-testing

I have very old legacy code. Before starting refactoring I want to make some unit tests for the code. But the bad thing is that files relies on each other with "require_once" statements (hovewer, functions I want to test is isolated).

So I can't write normal tests if I will not be able to mock "require_once" statement.

I'm using Kahlan framework for testing. So is it possible to mock such statements? If yes, than how?

Comment: Since `require_once` is a PHP statement, that's somewhere between very hard and impossible to mock. However, unless some undesirable code gets executed, files simply including each other isn't necessarily a deal breaker for unit tests, no?

Comment: @deceze I know that Kahlan allows Monkey-patching (e.g. for built-in functions) in a specific way: It copies files, replaces some built-in functions in this code with his own code and then performs tests on this "new" code. This approach also can be useful for mocking "require_once" or any other statements, so the question was born. And, unfortunately, some of the required files performs unwanted side code.

Comment: @deceze I made workaround for this problem. If you interested, you can see my answer.

Comment: You need functional tests, not unit tests.

Comment: @mike I need them too, but functional tests are very slow and harder to write.

Comment: Crappy code can't be unit tested. This is pointless too as unit tests are about testing the behavior, not the implementation.

Comment: @mike can you explain, please? I always thought that unit tests must ensure that each part of code (class method or, in case of crappy code, function) separately works well. It is "implementation", right? So why it is pointless?

Comment: Not "works well" but does what it is supposed to do, this is a huge difference. If you test the implementation (meaning step by step what the code does), your tests become fragile and you become forced to modify them with any change to the code being tested. For instance if a method returns a configuration array you want to assert that an array was returned, not to compare exactly what's inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not possible.

However, I have made a plugin to Kahlan that allows to "extract" functions from any file and skip all other code. It will not allow to exactly "mock" statements, but it will allow to test isolated functions. I made pull-request and if it will not be accepted, I will make a separate packagist composer packet and update this answer.

Changes can be found here:

https://github.com/lamp-of-god/kahlan/tree/isolator-plugin

Example of usage:

File:

```
<?php
require_once 'something';  // This string will be "skipped" on test

do_something();  // This string too

function test()
{
    return 42;
}
```

Test for this file with plugin:

```
<?php

use Kahlan\Plugin\Isolator;

Isolator::isolate(dirname(__DIR__).'/../test.php');

describe('test()', function() {
    it('returns 42', function() {
        expect(test())->toBe(42);
    });
});
```